# Как найти и определить позицию одной строки в другой НЕ используя indexOf?

Tags: java

Как можно определить позицию строки x в строке y не используя метод indexOf, а пользуясь лишь charAt для определения позиции?

Я понимаю, что необходимо сначала посчитать количество символов, перебрать и сравнить на наличие во второй строке, но как корректно и максимально эффективно это сделать?

Пример:

String x = "bla"
String y = "usblabla"

Ответ функции должен выдавать 2 в этом примере.

Comment: максимально эффективно никак. вам в любом случае придется перебирать символы строки по порядку и сравнивать их с искомым текстом

Comment: Можете обратиться к одному из [этих](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Поиск_подстроки_в_строке) алгоритмов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считать ничего не надо. И судя по формулировке вопроса, вам надо не максимально эффективно, а максимально просто, чтобы было понятно, как это работает. Тут теоретически не приветствуются вопросы с просьбами сделать за вас домашнее задание, но практически на это правило почти никто не обращает внимания, так что вот вам решение, а мне небольшое упражнение.

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Ru_So_1372645_FindSubstring {

  private final static String[][] TEST_DATA = {
    {"ablablablya", "abla"},
    {"ablablablya", "bla"},
    {"ablablablya", "bly"},
    {"ablablablya", "blya"},
    {"ablablably",  "blya"},
    {"ablablablya", "lba"},
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String[] ss: TEST_DATA) {
      testSearchSubstring(ss[1], ss[0]);
    }
  }

  private static void testSearchSubstring(String searchArg, String s) {
    int index = findSubstring(searchArg, s);
    if (index >= 0) {
      System.out.printf("'%s' contains '%s' at index %d\n", s, searchArg, index);
    } else {
      System.out.printf("'%s' does not contain '%s'\n", s, searchArg);
    }

  }

  private static int findSubstring(String searchArg, String s) {
    int argLength = searchArg.length();
  MAIN_LOOP:
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - argLength; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < argLength; j++) {
        if (s.charAt(i + j) != searchArg.charAt(j))
          continue MAIN_LOOP;
      }
      return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }

}
```

Это самый простой и наименее эффективный алгоритм, решение "в лоб". Если вам реально нужны более эффективные алгоритмы, то смотрите, например, в книге Р. Седжвик, К. Уэйн, "Алгоритмы на Java"